# Vector function of distance traveled.

Tags: analysis, functions, vectors

Let the scenario be the following:

We have a driving car whose start velocity is $100\frac{m}{s}$ and it's brakes reduce the velocity by $10\frac{m}{s}$, quite simple.

If we were to make a vector function of **distance-traveled vs velocity**.

The velocity would be equal to:

$$y(t)=v - v_{brake}\cdot t$$

Because, for every time step, the brakes reduce the speed by the amount listed above eg $v_{brake}\cdot t$.

The distance traveled:

$$x(t)=y(t)\cdot t$$

My reasoning being:

$$distance = v\cdot t$$

A plot of the vector function:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okNVs.png)

Although this might seem pretty reasonable, it should be clear that the units don't add up.
Velocity would be $\frac{m}{s} - m$, which is illegal according to the physics police. This would also invalidate the second function for distance traveled. I've probably overlooked something important.

Sorry for asking such a simple question.

Comment: $$x(t) = y(t) * t = t(v - v_{brake} * t) = vt - v_{brake} * t^2 = [LT^{-1} * T] - [LT^{-2} * T^2] = [L] - [L] = [L]$$  Which is dimensionally correct. I think you made a mistake by considering $v_{brake}$ as velocity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brakes reduce it's velocity by $10$ m/s in every second. So the acceleration is $-10 \, \text{m/s}^2$.

So
$$y(t)=v-10\,\text{ms}^{-2}t$$

$$x(t)=100\,\text{ms}^{-1}t+\frac{1}{2}(-10\,\text{ms}^{-2})t^2$$